# How to get rows with No values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

I have a table that holds financial transactions data per account.

```
**FinTransMaster table:**
------------------------------------
|AcctID  |FinTrnsCode|BusinessDay  |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |INTRST     |2017-09-09   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |CHARGE     |2017-09-08   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |PYMNT      |2017-09-01   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |INTRST     |2017-08-19   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |INTRST     |2017-08-09   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |CHARGE     |2017-08-04   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |PYMNT      |2017-08-01   |
------------------------------------
|1234567 |INTRST     |2017-07-19   |
------------------------------------
```

I want to select the last time a payment was made on each account.

**So my code is as follows:**

```
SELECT AcctID
      ,[FinTransCode]
      --,MAX([BusinessDay])  --Tried this line, doesn't work
      --,ISNULL(MAX([BusinessDay]), 'Never Paid') Last_Paid --Tried this line too, doesn't work
      ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(MAX([BusinessDay]), 0) = 0 THEN 'Never Paid'
            ELSE MAX([BusinessDay])
       END Last_Paid

  FROM [GEB_DWH].[dbo].[FinTransMaster]

  WHERE AcctID = '1234567'
    AND FinTransTypeCode = 'PYMT'

  GROUP BY AcctID,[FinTransTypeCode]
```

This code doesn't work because, some accounts HAVE NEVER PAID, EVER. Hence some accounts don't have the 'PYMNT' code at all in that field. They have the other codes in that field but no PYMNT code in that field. So, when I run that code for that AcctID, I get only the headers and NO results.

How do I show a 'Never Paid' in that field for that AcctID so that I can join it with another results table?

**What I'm eventually trying to get, by Joining with AcctID:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|AcctID  |ContactName|Phone Number |Email Address |Last Payment |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|1234567 |John Doe   |123-123-1234 |test@123.com  |Never Paid   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: why is the value 'Never Paid' for your sample data where in fact the last payment was |1234567 |PYMNT      |2017-09-01   |?

Comment: your query only consists of tuples from one table, which I assume only contains transactions, hence it cannot contain any row from accounts that never paid. you probably want `from finacct left join fintransmaster using (acctid)` (if your account table is called finacct)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
--Summary Stats by transaction type
    SELECT
    AcctID,
    FinTrnsCode,
    lastActivityDt = max(BusinessDay)
    into #temp
    FROM FinTransMaster 
    group by AcctID,FinTrnsCode

    --Find out all customers with Pmts
    SELECT 
    distinct
    ACCTID,
    LastPmtDate = LastActivityDt
    into #temp2
    FROM #temp where FinTrnsCode = 'PYMNT'

    SELECT ACCTID,
    LastPmtDate = cast(LastPmtDate as varchar(50))  FROM #temp2
    union
    --Get all customers with no pmt records
    SELECT distinct ACCTID, 'Never Paid' FROM #Temp where ACCTID not in (SELECT distinct ACCTID FROM #temp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the conditional from the `where` to the `select`:

```
SELECT AcctID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FinTransCode = 'PYMT' THEN BusinessDay END) as LastPayment
FROM [GEB_DWH].[dbo].[FinTransMaster]
 GROUP BY AcctID;
```

This sets the value to `NULL` if someone has not paid.  If you want a string, you need to convert the date to a string so the types are compatible.